# How do I use KIdleTime

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma

(http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kidletime/html/kidletime_8cpp_source.html)

How can I find out the idle time of a KDE program using KIdleTime. It has function

int KIdleTime::idleTime() const

but just using

KIdleTime::idleTime()

gives compilation error "undefined reference"

Comment: how do you generate makefile?did you included link flags?

Comment: How do you link against KIdleTime?

Answer (score 0):

It's a member function, you need an instance to be able to call it.

The class is a singleton, which means there is an instance already created for you - see [instance()](http://api.kde.org/frameworks-api/frameworks5-apidocs/kidletime/html/classKIdleTime.html#ab9ad9b9f2c2be68547b625bd07e46744)